# How to explain this arrangement for :cljsbuild on a Clojure/ClojureScript project? And how to extend it for Continuous Deployment?

Tags: build, release, clojurescript, leiningen, shadow-cljs

I have been dealing with this Clojure/Clojurescript project called [clojurescript.csv](https://github.com/testdouble/clojurescript.csv).

On the `project.clj` [file](https://github.com/testdouble/clojurescript.csv/blob/main/project.clj) there is [a special form](https://github.com/testdouble/clojurescript.csv/blob/f361708fcaaf19b40f99ae37ffa93d719e0ce9bc/project.clj#L10) of construction for `:cljsbuild` which I haven't seen yet.

```clj
  :cljsbuild {:builds [{:id "whitespace"
                        :source-paths ["src" "test"]
                        :compiler {:output-to "target/js/whitespace.js"
                                   :optimizations :whitespace
                                   :pretty-print true}}
                       {:id "simple"
                        :source-paths ["src" "test"]
                        :compiler {:output-to "target/js/simple.js"
                                   :optimizations :simple
                                   :pretty-print true}}
                       {:id "advanced"
                        :source-paths ["src" "test"]
                        :compiler {:output-to "target/js/advanced.js"
                                   :optimizations :advanced
                                   :pretty-print false}}]
```

Usually, I see a *brief* declaration, such as:

```clj
:source-paths ["src"]
```

On this repository the approach is different. Although each "build path" uses the same `source-path` there are different ids and optimizations route.

1 - What is the point on having these different ids for builds? How can this be useful?

I do not see it.

2 - Also, I would like to extend this file for Continuous Deployment (publishing a Maven package on GitHub registry). Usually, below the `source-paths`, I add the following:

```clj
source-paths ["src"]
  ;; Change your environment variables (maybe editing .zshrc or .bashrc) to have:
  ;; export LEIN_USERNAME="pdelfino"
  ;; export LEIN_PASSWORD="your-personal-access-token-the-same-used-on-.npmrc"
  ;; LEIN_PASSWORD should use the same Token used by .npmrc
  ;; Also, do "LEIN_SNAPSHOTS_IN_RELEASE=true lein install" or edit your .zshrc:
  ;; export LEIN_SNAPSHOTS_IN_RELEASE=true
  :repositories {"releases"  {:url           "https://maven.pkg.github.com/tallyfor/*"
                              :username      :env/LEIN_USERNAME ;; change your env
                              :password      :env/LEIN_PASSWORD}}

  :pom-addition [:distribution-management [:repository [:id "github"]
                                           [:name "GitHub Packages"]
                                           [:url "https://maven.pkg.github.com/my-organization/repository-name"]]]
```

Should I add it 3 times? One for every id?

It feels very repetitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lein-cljsbuild` allows you to specify [multiple build configurations](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild#multiple-build-configurations) like this. When compiling you may provide the id of the build you want to build. So, instead of just `lein cljsbuild once` you do `lein cljsbuild once advanced`.

This is common so you can have an unoptimized development build and a `:advanced` optimized release build. Usually you'd have a few more differences in build configs, eg. at least the `advanced` build not including `"test"` source path. Since this is a library project, this however is fine. The authors likely wanted to test with different optimization levels easily.

`:repositories` and `:pom-addition` are top level or alias/profile definitions in `project.clj`. They do not go into the `:cljsbuild` config map.